# How to load load files using list.files

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I have the following code:

```
files <- list.files(paste("R Ready Data",group,week,sep = "\\"))
for (file in files){
load(paste("R Ready Data",group,week,file,sep="\\"))
..........
```

This used to work just fine until last week. Since then I moved the folder of this project to another location. Since then I am having the following problem:
i) list.files() finds the files, as expected
ii) load() gives the error

> Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
> cannot open compressed file 'R Ready Data\transgenic\week 1\30_video_2021-08-25T15_19_09DLC_resnet50_Overuse1-Lisa-2021-01-04Jan4shuffle1_750000.Rdata', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

I tried the same comments with full paths (i.e. "C/R Project/R Ready Data..."). It still doesn't work.

Today I used the built-in file explorer of RStudio. For some reason it doesn't show the files, even though they can be seen in the File Explorer of Windows.

Comment: Already tried the `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)` argument?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too... It doesn't work. I think the problem is not about coding perse but for some reason RStudio's file explorer, which doesn't show the files.

Comment: This explorer only can show what `ls()` shows, check if `ls()` shows your files.

Comment: ls() shows the objects loaded in the environment. By "file explorer" I mean the tab "Files" bellow the environment, where you can navigate to different folders. So the folders were the files are supposed to be are empty. I can see the files in both MATLAB and Windows's File Explorer, so it's definitely something off with RStudio

Comment: The _Files_ tab might be not the right place to look for. `load` only affects the _Environment_ tab. _Files_ is basically the same as your OS browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with OneDrive and RStudio. When I moved my files outside the OneDrive folder it worked just fine.